# Play Framework 2.2 - could not find implicit value for parameter timeout

Tags: scala, playframework-2.2

I am testing a call using the following code:

```
"status OK" in {
  status(doFakeRequest) === OK
}
```

The call to `status` gives the following compile error:
`could not find implicit value for parameter timeout: akka.util.Timeout`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because the `Helpers` functions have changed. The timeout can now be changed for each function.

I needed to add the following import:

```
import play.api.test.Helpers.defaultAwaitTimeout
```